# How to put multiple layers in one frame using R?

Tags: r, overlay, layer

I'm using R to plot map files.

```
setwd("c:\\apa\\")
# Load libraries
library("maptools")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("classInt")
library("R2wd")
library("Hmisc")
library("plyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("rgdal")

file.path <- "c:\\apa\\"
file.name <- "apa_planalto_central"
apa <-readShapePoly(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))

file.name <- "AUTORIZACAO_09889652011"
auth <-readShapePoly(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))

file.name <- "CLIP_HIDROGRAFIA_APA"
hidro <-readShapeLines(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))

file.name <- "ferrovias"
ferrovias <-readShapeLines(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))

file.name <- "lagos_df"
lagos <-readShapePoly(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))

file.name <- "limite_df"
limites <-readShapeLines(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))

file.name <- "rodovias"
rodovias <-readShapeLines(paste(file.path,file.name,sep=""))


plot(apa)
plot(...)
```

I'd like to plot all these shapes (lines and Polygons) using one plot, overlaying all the layers, multiple layers over a single plot. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
plot(apa)
plot(auth, add=T)
```

Just use the `add=T` within the `plot()` function.

Answer (score 3):

In ggplot2 you can stack multiple geometries. This would something like:

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = pointset1) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = z), data = polyset1) +
  etc
```

This assumes that all datasets are in the same projection, all use the column name x for the x-coordinate etc. Note that ggplot2 works with data.frames, not sp objects. Use the function fortify to transform SpatialPolygons objects to a data.frame.